# Как узнать какая кнопка на AppearanceButton нажата пользователем?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Как узнать какая кнопка на AppearanceButton нажата пользователем? Хочу каждой кнопке назначить свою команду, но не могу разобраться с контролом. Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы имеете ввиду не AppearanceButton, а [Windows UI Button Panel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114583).Если вы используете WindowsUIButtonPanel, тогда для того чтобы обработать нажатие кнопки можно использовать события [WindowsUIButtonPanel.ButonClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonClicktopic) или [WindowsUIButtonPanel.ButtonChecked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPanel_ButtonCheckedtopic).

Comment: С событиями понятно, но вопрос в том, как обратиться к конкретной кнопке. Ответ нашел на официальном сайте devexpress